# ArcGIS Layer to KML scale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, google-earth, layer-to-kml

I am trying to create a KML from a layer composed of a large number of polygons.  Because of the large size, it is quite slow to load the KML in Google Earth.  Is there any way to create the KML so that it is only the polygons that are in the display area are visible?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and find out about the requirements for a good question. Specifically, what have you tried so far to find a solution?

Comment: Most tools that take a layer as input will work within the selected row set for that layer. Did you try a spatial query first? All in all, KML is big and slow, so you really ought to be looking to filter coordinate density, reduce coordinate display width, and/or use `.kmz` to reduce the file size